# What is the solution for the render process crashed error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building WebView in flutter, but following error occured:

> ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (5232) crash detected (code -1)

```
class WebViewClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewClassState createState() => _WebViewClassState();
}

class _WebViewClassState extends State<WebViewClass> {
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: "http://hackathonsnear.me/",
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know which plugin you are using currently maybe its issue in library.I suggest please use this [flutter_webview_plugin 0.3.11](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin/example) to get rid of this issue